# Is it possible to reference the same foreign key in multiple columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm currently trying to set up a database that has both 'question' and 'answer' table.

They look like this:

answer:

```
answer_id : PK int
answer_text : varchar
```

question:

```
question_id : PK int
question_text: varchar
correct_answer : FK answer.answer_id
incorrect_answer1 : FK answer.answer_id
incorrect_answer2 : FK answer.answer_id
incorrect_answer3 : FK answer.answer_id
```

my issue is that I can't seem to be able to reference the same foreign key (answer_id) for more than one column in my question table, any help would be appreciated.

Below is the error:

```
ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `hons_proj`.`question` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `answers fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`correct_answer` , `incorrect_answer1` , `incorrect_answer2` , `incorrect_answer3`)
  REFERENCES `hons_proj`.`answer` (`answer_id` , `answer_id` , `answer_id` , `answer_id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

and the CREATE TABLE statement used:

```
'question', 'CREATE TABLE `question` (\n  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `correct_answer` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `incorrect_answer1` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `incorrect_answer2` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `incorrect_answer3` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,\n  `question_text` varchar(64) NOT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),\n  UNIQUE KEY `question_text_UNIQUE` (`question_text`),\n  KEY `category fk_idx` (`category_id`),\n  KEY `answers fk_idx` (`correct_answer`,`incorrect_answer1`,`incorrect_answer2`,`incorrect_answer3`),\n  CONSTRAINT `category fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`category_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Please ignore the \n's.

Comment: It should be possible. Show us your create table DDL.

Comment: Fix your data model so you have a table with "question" and "answer" and a separate row for each answer.

Comment: You need 4 separate fk's. But listen to Gordon's advice before you do anything.

Comment: @jarlh i've added the Create table statement

Comment: Great! You've already got the answers needed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure I understand what you mean, my intent was to have each answer occupy a row in the 'answer' table with it's own unique answer_id

Comment: GordonLinoff seems to be referring to the fact that you should have one incorrect_answer column not 3. PS Why have you not read the manual sections on FKs, which tell you what is wrong with your declaration? PS A FK is a list of columns each of whose subrow values must appear uniquely under corresponding columns in another list. A declaration declares one FK constraint. The FK is in the referencing table, not the referenced table.